# Trying to search for a string within command output

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I'm writing a script to run PSinfo (from the Sysinternals suite) against a list of machines, then I want to search the output for a specific string before doing other things. The basic code is as follows:

```
with open ("specific-pcs.txt") as machines:
    line = []
    for machineName in machines:
        machineName = machineName.strip()

        ps_Info = subprocess.Popen("location of PsInfo \\" + machineName + " -s").communicate()[0]

        if ("Silverlight" in ps_Info):
            subprocess.Popen("wmic product where caption='Microsoft Silverlight' call uninstall")
            print "Uninstalling Silverlight"
        else:   
            pass
```

The output of PsInfo looks something like this:

```
Microsoft Office Word MUI (English) 2010 14.0.7015.1000
Microsoft ReportViewer 2010 Redistributable 10.0.30319
Microsoft Silverlight 5.1.10411.0
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148 9.0.30729.4148
Realtek High Definition Audio Driver 6.0.1.7004
```

But running the code as is, it complains that "'Nonetype' is not iterable".
All I need it to do is say if Silverlight (in this case) exists in the output or not.
What do I need to change?

Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

`communicate` returns `None` for a stream if it is not redirected to a pipe, which means in your case:

```
subprocess.Popen("location of PsInfo \\" + machineName + " -s").communicate()
```

will return `(None, None)`, and when using the `in` operator on `None` you get the `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` error.

Also, you should use a list of arguments when calling `Popen` instead of a single string, so this should work:

```
ps_Info = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Path\To\PsInfo", r"\\" + machineName, "-s"],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @mata. Whenever I add the [ ] brackets and the stdout=subprocess.PIPE bit, python is then "unable to find the file specified" when the script is run, that's with the +'s or commas as per your example... Any idea why that is?

Comment: Did you use the full path to PsInfo, and if you use backslashes in a string, you should use a raw string `r'...'`. updated my answer, I also forgot to add the backslashes in front of the machine name.

Comment: I did, yes, with the 'r'. The only difference if it finds it or not are whether I include the [ ] brackets and the stdout=subprocess.PIPE bits.

Comment: strange... I don't really have any experience with that tool, so I dont't know why it doesn't work... If the path to the executable is correct, then it should work.

Comment: Hi All,
I'm still having problems with the '-s' switch on this command. It doesn't matter if I put it before or after the machineName, but it just gets ignored! I know the switch is correct when it's run direct from cmd. Is there anything else I can try to make sure the command works with the '-s' switch??